# Apache2 virtualhost configuration Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, apache2, virtualhost

I've looked at all the answers I can find for Apache virtual hosts not working, and I'm still stumped.  I'm using Ubuntu 16.04LTS and I'm on an instance with Google cloud.  I've tested my configuration on localhost and it works (using same O/S, same software installed).  Except I use dummy names and put them in /etc/hosts.

I've enabled ssl, edited /etc/apache2/apache2.conf to AllowOverride All for /var/www/, used a2dissite 000-default.conf, and I'm still having problems getting the virtual hosts to work.  They are all port 443, and with a sample config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/testsite.network
   ServerName testsite.network
   ServerAlias www.testsite.network
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

and sudo a2ensite testsite.network.conf, and sudo service apache2 reload, whenever I try to reach a site https://testsite.network in this case, Apache always serves the default file in the default document root.  It doesn't seem to be recognising any virtual hosts or serving from the correct document root.

Any ideas?  I'm just out of ways to try and diagnose this problem.  I don't even know where to look to try and find out what's going on.  All I know is that whenever I try to set up a vhost and enable it, the default document root is set for it, and the default page comes up.

Comment: "whenever I try to reach a site" How do you do that ? with a browser ? curl ? wget ? openssl s_command ?

Comment: With both, browser and curl.  I have the domain names set up in CloudFlare pointing to the correct IP for the server.

Comment: is there or is there not `testsite.network` in `/etc/hosts` file?